# Suggest a simple Java math library for matrix operations for use with OpenGL (lwjgl)

Tags: java, math, opengl, lwjgl, frustum

I'm writing an OpenGL app with Java. I need to do some math for camera and frustum culling (for AABB). Could you suggest a simple and fast Java math library for that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Jama](http://math.nist.gov/javanumerics/jama/) is pretty simple and fast.

Comment: ... but not awailable on maven central

Answer (score 1):

http://commons.apache.org/math/ - if you prefer apache

Answer (score 0):

[EJML](http://ejml.org/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page) is another linear algebra library which may worth looking:

> Efficient Java Matrix Library (EJML) is a linear algebra library for
>   manipulating real/complex/dense/sparse matrices. Its design goals are;
>   1) to be as computationally and memory efficient as possible for both
>   small and large matrices, and 2) to be accessible to both novices and
>   experts. These goals are accomplished by dynamically selecting the
>   best algorithms to use at runtime, clean API, and multiple interfaces.
>   EJML is free, written in 100% Java and has been released under an
>   Apache v2.0 license.